# Linux-Change line between two awk scripts

Tags: linux, awk

I have two awk scripts to run in Linux. The output of each one is in one line.
How can I separate the two output into two lines?

For example:

```
awk '{printf $1}' f.txt >> a.txt
awk '{printf $3}' f.txt >> a.txt
```

The output of the first script is:

```
35 56 40 28 57
```

And the second output is:

```
29 48 73 26
```

If I run them one after another, the output will become:

```
35 56 40 28 57 29 48 73 26
```

Is there any way to get the result to:

```
35 56 40 28 57
29 48 73 26
```

Thank you!~

Comment: just use `print` instead of `printf` or do `printf $1"\n"`

Comment: But I have multiple numbers each line. If I use "print", there will be only one number in each line. Any ideas?

Comment: in that case you need to provide more information on the input/output and the structure of your main script

Comment: Hi, I have update the description. Hope that makes it clear. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I don't understand how you manage to get the spaces between fields the way you do it, you can add an `END` statement to the first script:

```
awk '{printf $1} END{print "\n"}'
```

You can also do this with a single awk command:

```
awk -v ORS=" " 'BEGIN{ARGV[ARGC++] = ARGV[1]; i = 1 } 
                NR!=FNR && FNR==1 { printf "\n"; i=3 } 
                { print $i } 
                END { printf "\n" }' f.txt
```